# How to remove permission on a certan user role in wp

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a user role `Author` on my wordpress to publish post but on its admin dashboard it shows the `Page Management menu` which is I want to remove it. I try to install plugin such as `User Role Editor` and `Capability Manager Enhanced` but still on the `Author` admin page shows the 'Page Management Menu`.

My question is how can I remove the `Page Management Menu` and its functionality from user role `Author`?

Comment: Removing of the Page Management menu is not possible. The way is just by not customzing the rights. Because there always needs to be an admin and other users.

Comment: You don't want the author to be able to access pages on their dashboard?

Comment: yup.. well on my local the author dashboard doesn't have the 'page management menu'. I am wondering on the live the author dashboard have it.